# Web site Preview

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on a porject in which i have Stream Posting like facebook, 
Users can also post link of any website, i want to implement it like facebook, ie when user post a link,it'll show website preview below the textbox, I have no idea how can i accomplish this
How can i achieve this functionality, I am using Ajax call to posting on stream

```
$.ajax({
                url: "My Controller ActionResult",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ objResourceModel: objResource, objTagList: TagTypeList, sendEmail: $("#chkbxSendEmail")[0].checked, groupId: ResourceVariable.GroupId, isblog: isblog, isquest: isquest }),
                dataType: "html",
                contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#btnPost").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    loading = setTimeout("$('#load').show()", 200);
                },
                complete: function () {
                    clearTimeout(loading);
                    $("#load").hide();
                    $("#btnPost").removeAttr("disabled");
                },
                success: function (Result) {
                    if (Result == "false") {
                        alert("Video must be of Youtube or vimeo");
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#divResourceDetails').html(Result);
                        ClearPostSectionData(); //function call
                        SetUpCommentSectionEvent(); //function call set up events
                        GetLatestAnnouncements();
                        $('#tagOutput').html("");
                        outputTagHtml = '';
                        TagTypeList = [];
                        //GetBrowseByInstructor(); //function call
                        //GetBrowseByTagType(); //function call
                        GetBrowseByResource(); //function call
                        GetBrowseByMonth(); //function call
                    }
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert("Unable to save uploaded post details: " + msg.responseText);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

As you need to effectively parse the HTML on the remote site (for things like the meta information in the head) you need to retrieve the HTML to process it.

While jQuery wont let you send/receive across origins (different domains - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) - except for "Padded JSON" (jsonp - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) - your server code can!

You can make an HttpWebRequest (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) for the URL, and then it is up to you whether or not to send the HTML to your JavaScript code to be parsed on the client, or you could parse it on the server and send a structured object to the client side code to simply push into a div.

By parsing the HTML server-side, it gives you an opportunity to cache it in a database (in case somebody else shares the same url), perhaps analyse it and record errors (you don't want your server to keep hitting a URL that returns a 404!).

Ultimately, you might want to simply return a Partial View (as you're using ASP.NET MVC), but you could be clever and return a specialised View depending on the content type. For example, Facebook lets you watch YouTube videos in-situ on the News Feed, and shows pictures in-line too. If you share a website, it often lets you pick from a selection of images it has found in the page you've shared.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it quick with an iframe in the page pointing to the url being shared. This is in case you just need the page preview and not to parse the html from that page to extract metadata like Facebook does.